# Reason for "yield return someObject" followed by "someObject = null"?

Tags: c#, return, yield

Does anyone know what the reasoning behind the following code is? This is generated in VS2010 from a web test.

```
yield return someObject;
someObject = null;
```

I saw this and thought it was weird, so I was wondering if anyone knew if this resulted in some sort of gain over letting someObject sit there as allocated memory. To be clear, the line in question is the 2nd statement, as yield return is fairly common. Setting the deferred return object to null is what bugs me.

EDIT: More context. The "yield return" is executed in a method that returns IEnumerable, which results in deferred execution. someObject is a method-scoped variable.

Thanks!

Comment: Who knows?  Without the context (and specifically, knowing whether `someObject` is a class member or local) it's impossible to say.

Comment: Thanks, edited with some more context!

Comment: Why not just paste in your whole method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET is pretty good at determining when a local variable is no longer used, and the object referenced becomes collectible even in the middle of a method, even while the variable is still in scope, as long as the compiler can prove it won't be accessed again.  Object lifetime in .NET is unrelated to scope.

So the line is completely useless, and actually may keep the object alive longer.  For the most part it's just harmless code emitted by a code generator, just like Kirill said.

However -- when the compiler encounters closures or coroutines (`yield return` creates a co-routine) then local variables get promoted to members of a helper class.  And class members can't be collected early.  So assigning `null` may be needed to make it unreachable.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, and the insight into how .NET handles yield statements!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its related to deferred execution on the containing method? Since you have to yield to an IEnumerable result, we can assume there's some deferred execution going on.

Answer (score 0):

Once this is generated code, it is likely that this is result of "non elegant code" in other place. Generated code varies from case to case. This means that is more difficult to check it than the human written code.

I easily can imagine that in other, maybe more complex scenario, this would be important. And here this is just a useless line that do not harm anybody..